# How to implement this multi-threading scenario in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to do something like this:

```
function void DoSomething(string path){
    try {
        DownloadDataFromWebSite(path)
    }catch(OtherUserLoggedInUsingSameAcountException ex){         
         If (I am the first thread that get here){
              Login();
        }else{
             Wait for the first thread to finish Login();
        }        
        DownloadDataFromWebSite(path);   
    }        
}
```

I have a collection that I will call like this:

```
 APathCollection.AsParallel().ForAll(DoSomething)
```

Please help me, How can I implement this pattern? Is it possible?

PS: I have omitted the error counter, please assume it will not get into an infinite recurring.

**Update:** I have updated the code to reflect what I am really doing on @IPValverde request.

Comment: Side note: Why are you recursing at all? What's wrong with a loop?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I think the OP is trying to force a retry on `DoWork(x)` by recursing.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah, I understand, but it's a nasty abuse of recursion. A loop would work fine.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - yes, agreed.

Comment: @LeY - Can you explain what kind of exception `particularException` is and why you can get it only once and how it can be fixed? What's the nature of this exception?

Comment: @Enigmativity the problem I trying to solve is a racing login with other user/application. but another example could be a buffer is full, then i go clear or flush the buffer, the exception will get fixed.

Comment: @LeY - Can the buffer get filled more than once? And how is the full buffer "fixed"?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, why not? It get fiexed by handling whatever in the buffer , then the buffer will be empty again.

Comment: @LeY - Then your question becomes invalid - if the exception can be thrown multiple times you can't have one thread fix the issue and all others bypass it. You need to fix each and every time.

Comment: @Enigmativity Why is it invalid? I don't get it . I am not let all other thread bypass it,  I need other threads to wait while one thread is fixing it , then other thread can retry it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85266/discussion-between-ley-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 1):

OK, you gave more information on your scenario. I think you can create a second lock indicating if one of your threads are logging-in.

Here is a snippet:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Program().Execute();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        // lock objects
        this.fixErrorLock = new object();
        this.isLoggingInLock = new object();

        var objectsToIterate = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };

        objectsToIterate.AsParallel().ForAll(this.DoWork);
    }

    private object isLoggingInLock;
    private object fixErrorLock;


    private bool isLoggingIn;
    public bool IsThereAnyThreadLoggingIn()
    {
        lock (this.isLoggingInLock)
        {
            // If no thread is logging-in, the one who asked is going to log-in
            if (!this.isLoggingIn)
                this.isLoggingIn = true;

            return this.isLoggingIn;
        }
    }

    public void DoWork(int myParam)
    {
        try
        {
            if (myParam % 4 == 0)
                throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Is the equivalent of 'is the first thread to hit here?'
            bool canLogIn = this.IsThereAnyThreadLoggingIn();

            // Every thread with error will stop here
            lock (fixErrorLock)
            {
                // But only the first one will do the login process again
                if (canLogIn)
                {
                    // Inside the login method the variable responsible for the 'isFirstThread' is restored to false
                    this.LogIn();
                }
            }

            this.DoWork(myParam-1);
        }
    }

    public void LogIn()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        lock (this.isLoggingInLock)
        {
            // The login is done
            this.isLoggingIn = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see this example running here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SOXxO9

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. Stack Overflow answers should be able to stand alone if the external site goes away. You should put the code directly in the answer. You can always add the link then as a convenience.

Comment: @IPValverde this will not work because once errorFixed set to ture, it will not be able to set back to false anymore.  so there will be no further exception handling if the exception happen again. And no matter where you set it back to false, it's not thread-safe with this approch I guess.  I changed your demo a little , so you can see the problem https://dotnetfiddle.net/xgaTmM

Comment: Looks like you've updated your code, so now we can get rid of the book variable and always wait on lock, since every thread has to fix the problem.

Comment: @IPValverde Book variable? Not every thread has to fix the problem, you don't know when this problem will happen. I need to handle it whenever it happens and keeping doing work if it doesn't.

Comment: I mean get rid of the errorFixed variable. Not every thread has to fix the problem? Well if you are in the catch you know the problem happened so you probably want to fix it, right? I updated the dotnetfiddle example

Comment: @IPValverde Your changes will cause all threads to fix the problem again and again, but the problem only need to be fixed once, I know the problem happened when I was in the catch, that's why i need to wait and skip , not wait and fix again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85264/discussion-between-ley-and-ipvalverde).

Comment: @LeY It looks like if an error occurs in one thread, other threads may have the same error, this is weird, it seems that your DoWork method just "breaks" with an wrong parameter and it break to every thread. The "DoWork" method SHOULD be stateless, it should do its work based on the parameter it receives without changing another thread's behavior.
I think you should show an example of what your "DoWork" method does.

Comment: @IPValverde Code updated , it should make more sense now.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have an answer for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you are talking about thread safety, it's the resources that are important.

So first [read about lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), especially the parts referring to critical sections.

Then, create a lock for each "logical" resource  in the `FixparticularException` method and you should be fine. If you give some particulars I could write the code for you more explicitly, bit here is the gist:

```
private bool _IsFixed;

public void DoSomething(int x)
{
    try 
    {
        DoWork(x)
    }
    catch (ParticularException pex)
    {
          FixParticularException(pex);
    }        
    DoSomething(x);   
}        

private void FixParticularException (ParticularException pex)
{
    lock (_resource1Lock)
    {
         if (_IsFixed)
             return;

        // fix it

        _IsFixed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your comment. Could you please expound  @Enigmativity?

Comment: If two threads throw `ParticularException` and call `FixParticularException` one will go into the `lock` and the other will have to wait. But when the first thread exits the second will then enter the lock and run the `// fix it` code. The OP only wants one thread to run `// fix it`.

Comment: That is not the logic of his post. He wants to wait and then fix it once the resource is available.

Comment: Ah formatting issue on my phone. Ill fix the answer

Comment: Why the two downvotes? The logic as stated on my phone showed the fix exception on two different lines. I have now fixed the logic.

Comment: You still have a logic problem with this solution. Say two threads hit the lock at the same time. One goes into the lock, sees that both `_IsFixing` & `_IsFixed` are `false` so proceeds to set `_IsFixing` to `true` and then exits the lock. The second thread is now free to enter the lock, but the first thread may take some time to run the `// fix it` code, yet the second thread has hit the `return` statement and has gone back to try reprocessing **before** the first thread has completed the fix.

Comment: Yep good call...fixed. So the real answer is dont answer on this site at night from my phone.

Comment: @ibgib You are getting into the same old issue That is you can't flip the _IsFixed flag back to false which will prevent further exception handling. I need further exception handling , this exception could happen again, And I don't know when.

Comment: This was written before that constraint was added to the question.. It is the same approach  as @IPValverde so I have nothing to add to the question. I will remove my answer as y'all have already discussed it in further detail.

Comment: I apparently cant remove the answer so I'll let it stand as is.